# My wireless mouse receiver is not recognized by Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I own a Steelseries Rival 650 gaming mouse, which I acquired in December 2018. After a few months of not using my mouse, I plugged the wireless receiver back into  my computer, but the receiver won't connect to the computer, and a little notification pops up on my computer that says:

> USB device not recognized. The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it. Try reconnecting  the device. If Windows still does not recognize it, your device may not be working properly."

This happens whenever I plug the receiver into my computer, or any other computer that I have tried. My computer operates on Windows 10, if it helps. Is there anything I can do to salvage my 120 dollar mouse? Would buying a [new receiver](https://steelseries.com/gaming-accessories/rival-650-usb-wireless-transmitter-and-adapter) work? Can you somehow reprogram my mouse using the [Steelseries engine](https://steelseries.com/engine) to recognize a different receiver, if that would work? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you contacted Steelseries to see what options they recommend?

Comment: Not yet, was waiting to see if you guys had any opinions on what I should do.

Comment: If the symptom is the same across many computers the dongle is defective.